# Django - React - Google Cloud Storage SigedURL upload is not working

Tags: reactjs, django, google-cloud-storage, pre-signed-url

I have used signedURL with jquery/ajax and Django for uploading to Google Cloud Storage previously successfully.

However with the Django - React setup I have not been able to establish a successful. upload yet.

```
export const UploadVideo = async (form_data, file, signedurl, asset_uuid) => {
    let resultState = { state: '', data: {} };

    let config = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: signedurl,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'video/mp4',
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods':'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS'
        },
        data: form_data
    };

    await axios(config).then(function (response) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
        resultState.state = 'success';
    }).catch(function (error) {
        resultState.state = 'error';
        resultState.data.message = error.message;
        window.toastr.error(error.message);

        console.log(error)
    })

    return resultState;
}

export const CreateAssets = async (data, key) => {
    let resultState = { state: '', data: {} };

    await axios.get(`https://origin/asset/create/?category=1&title=%22` + data[key].title + `%22&size=1`)
        .then(res => {
            resultState.state = 'success';
            resultState.data = res.data;
        }).catch((err) => {
            resultState.state = 'error';
            resultState.data['message'] = err.message;
        })
    return resultState;
}
```

The code for react js get singed url and calling signedurl with the file dialog is available.

What shall I do for a succesful signedurl file upload to Google Cloud Storage ?

The CORS settings for the storage bucket is as follows :

```
# cat google-storage-cors.json                                       
[
    {
      "origin": ["https://www.videoo.io", "https://videoo.io", "http://localhost:8000", "localhost:3000", "http://localhost:3000", "https://storage.googleapis.com", "*"],
      "responseHeader": ["Content-Type","x-goog-resumable", "*"],
      "method": ["GET", "HEAD", "DELETE", "PUT", "POST", "OPTIONS"],
      "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
    }
]%

# gsutil cors set  google-storage-cors.json gs://production-my-storage
```

[image]

When I use the following curl command as suggested by @JohnHanley, the following is the output that I get :

```
% curl -X PUT --upload-file /Users/utku/Desktop/cat.mp4 "https://storage.googleapis.com/production-videoo-storage/b47a4ffd40be41f08c255b3f308d36e1?Expires=1654980179&GoogleAccessId=videoo-348016%40appspot.gserviceaccount.com&Signature=QDnQh%2FI3%2BHJiPj5htwdPn7JqWZH%2FNaogM0ZlzJCl4BZVks6T5Qa1GMCCvmjJZINM01lpB9S%2FZMqamyNHisFz%2FB2EDxstJMHtAbpdw7E%2BYSXmGYP2lLpsCqXAhXsncbyKJFwkcD%2BkX3yZGHGsbLqnJtQ3lghhJxjrprPdhj1zGg%2FwrnKEa5g2YdxI2LW6KAQFtV8zICitWn%2BhdGxzJK1LnTekcv1%2F7zILlN9RbPwdEGBJWd2F3VIGCtyrZSuNqOW66ptQ2TT7uMbM5guDPPq86eom3eHMEVlY4E%2BLeYf4RMBwJQ50QhH0%2BA4Vevd2%2Bfza92acgJUJRhOQ5Gr5rZ6TnA%3D%3D"


<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your Google secret key and signing method.</Message><StringToSign>PUT


1654980179
/production-videoo-storage/b47a4ffd40be41f08c255b3f308d36e1</StringToSign></Error>
```

Comment: Is this a typo **method: 'HOST',**? What are the CORS settings at Cloud Storage? Verify that the user/service-account has the correct IAM roles to grant Cloud Storage access. I usually try the signed URL using the CLI curl to separate CORS versus signing/permission problems. You can get a CORS error when the actual problem is with the signed URL.

Comment: @JohnHanley Can you please share a cli curl command to upload a video that is in my local storage to cloud storage if I have the signedurl.

Comment: Google search for how to use the CLI curl. There are numerous examples.

Comment: I have shared the cli command that I have used with curl in the ticket. 

Actually my problem might be this : I am creating the signedurl in Google App Engine with a service account. The permissions for the service account might have an effect on "SignatureDoesNotMatch".

Comment: Most likely that error means the HTTP headers you supplied when creating the Signed URL do not match the headers supplied when you use the Signed URL. Edit your question and show how you created the Signed URL. The sign and the request must match exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the signed url should be created with this function :

```
def get_signed_url_for_upload(path):
    blob = settings.STORAGE.bucket.blob(path)
    expiration_time = timezone.now() + timedelta(minutes=120)
    signed_url = blob.generate_signed_url(
        version="v4",
        # This URL is valid for 15 minutes
        expiration=timedelta(minutes=15),
        # Allow PUT requests using this URL.
        method="PUT",
        content_type="application/octet-stream",)
    return signed_url
```